# showing symbols in a specific order

Tags: arcgis-desktop, order, symbology

i'm trying to layout a map in ArcGIS09, showing samplings in a specific region:
i have a layer with samplings on different sampling dates and sites. sometimes, there are several samples at one site, done at different dates.

the attribute i want to layout is the population structure (very good, good, moderate, poor, bad), which is easy.
but now, i would like to sort the points in a way, that the older sampling dates are hidden by the more recent ones. and it would be even nicer, to layout the older sampling dates bigger than the more recent one, in a way that they are still visible below...

is this possible in any way?

thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You will get no answers unless you specify anything. Right now it looks like you're drawing your map by hand.

Comment: Agree with Ilja, also mention which software you're using - ArcGIS, QGIS...?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Beneath your Question there is an edit button that will enable you to revise it with the GIS software and version that you are using. These are probably the two most important pieces of information for me to know as a potential answerer.

Comment: ok, sorry, i'm really not so advanced in those things... i'm working with ArcGIS09. the sampling points are all on the same layer, but with different attributes.

Answer (score 2):

You may symbolize your points by the population structure and use **symbol levels** to define the drawling order:

> Symbol-level drawing allows you to achieve special cartographic
>   effects by giving you control over the drawing order of feature
>   symbology. You specify the order that symbols and symbol layers for
>   multilayer symbols are drawn on your map—overriding the default ArcMap
>   drawing sequence.

Additional information and instructions on how to enable this setting may be found from the link below:

[Working with symbol levels](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?id=299&pid=287&topicname=Working_with_symbol_levels)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is the Data Management>General>Sort

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000057000000